# Alpine Linux java No such file or directory

Tags: linux, java, alpine-linux, maven

when trying to install nodejs from a tar.gz and java, maven with sdkman on an alpine linux distro and running java or maven I get a message saying for java:

> /root/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java: No such file or
> directory.

for mvn:

> /root/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current/bin/mvn: exec: line 238:
> /root/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java: not found .

I understand that it could be a compatibility issue since java is compiled with glibc and alpine is based on a glibc variant called musl-libc.

So, I wanted to know of a solution other than having to download the code for these components and recompiling them with compatibility for musl.

by the way, the architecture of the Alpine is x86_64. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change Alpine with GLibC distribution.

Comment: you mean install glibc on alpine? or is there any Alpine linux distribution with glibc?. I've been looking and couldn't find any.

Comment: No, I mean to try RHEL, Debian, Ubuntu, SuSE, a lot of other distributions.

Comment: @RomeoNinov While this suggestion could possibly work, it is way outside the scope of the question. OP might have a good reason to use Alpine in this case and simply suggesting a different distribution is just a bad unnecessary advice. What would you tell your mechanic if he says "I don't know what the problem is with your squeaking wipers, but you could simply buy a different car"?

Comment: @mashuptwice, Alpine may have place with containers. In such case why do not use directly this: https://hub.docker.com/_/node

Comment: @RomeoNinov There are certainly other usecases for Alpine than containers, for example low-overhead systems like a PBX, as Dom0 for XEN, or as OS for custom embedded projects. Still, your recommendation is not very helpful, considering that the question was specifically about compiling maven on alpine, not about distro recommendations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62905753/maven-and-jdk8-on-alpine-linux-image

Comment: I am using Alpine because I am preparing a container with nodejs12, java8 and maven version 3.3.9 (with those particular versions, Developers and their peculiarities :) ).

I'm still working on the container. thanks for trying to help anyway.

Comment: To be fair, @Félix, your question doesn't --yet-- restrict answers from saying "don't use Alpine; use a glibc based distro". If using Alpine is a requirement, your question should say so. That's the result of clarifying comments :)

Comment: Hi @JeffSchaller , thanks for your response. It is not a strict requirement to use Alpine, but because of how light it is and considering the recommendations of the Docker Project, I opted for said distro. I may be wrong but, I think that I can gain in the use of resources (Mem, Cpu, etc) by using this Alpine, am I wrong? Greetings.